# How to add/modify an attribute to a Django class based view from a Decorator?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, python-decorators

I have a class-based Django view as follows:

```
class myView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'templateFile.html'
    request = None

    @method_decorator(request_management)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return super(myView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(newFeatures, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['requester'] = self.requester
        return ctx
```

In my request_management decorator, I would like to set the value of myView.request to the argument that was passed into the dispatch function. So I do something like this:

```
def request_management(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("request = %s" % str(args[0]))
        # I want to say here something like: 
        # self.request = args[0]
        # but of course, "self" is not defined in this context.
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

But from within the decorator, I can't access the "self" instance of the decorated method.
How can I get that instance and attach an attribute named request to it so that I can use that attribute in other methods of that instance?

Comment: I answered below, but are you aware that `self.request` is already created for you in class-based views? See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering).

Comment: No. I had no clue. Thank you! But there are other parameters I need to add to self as attributes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're doing this wrong. In my experience, overriding `dispatch` is almost never the right strategy. Also, when dealing with class-based views it's usually a good idea to consider using a mixin. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `method_decorator` is to [convert a function decorator into a method decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.method_decorator). But since you're writing your own decorator, you can just go ahead and write it as an actual method decorator:

```
class myView(TemplateView):

    @request_management
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... 
        return super(myView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def request_management(method): 
        @wraps(method)
        def decorator(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            logger.debug("request = %s" % str(request))
            self.request = request

            return method(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

        return decorator
```